# Boto DynamoDB2 conditional put_item

Tags: python, conditional-statements, boto, put

I am trying to have put_item to check if there is item with the same HashKey before actually adding the new item.

According to boto DynamoDB2 document, it is possible to do it with "Conditional Put".

I tried following command but no luck.

```
connection.put_item('table',item={'locationId':'a1', 'timestamp': time.time()}, expected={'locationID':False})
```

The error message is as following.

```
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'Message': u'Expected null', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException'}
```

Does anyone have a conditional put with DynamoDBv2?

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: You can tell DynamoDB to only store the item if there isn't already an item with the same primary key but in that case the ``expected`` clause would have to refer to that primary key, not ``False``.

Comment: @garnaat, Thank you for the comment. I think there may be multiple errors.  I tried the command even without `expected` part and still received the same error - `boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'Message': u'Expected null', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException'}`.  I wonder if there is any conditional `put_item()` examples that I can take a look... I tried google search but no luck.

Comment: @garnaat do you have any example codes that works with DynamodB v2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write it like this for the syntax to work. It's extremely bad that this isn't documented anywhere. I just had the exact same problem and had to try 50 different things while digging through the Java SDK documentation for it to work. Note that you need to give a value if you want to go with `'Exists': True` instead of `False`.

```
connection.put_item(
    'table',
    item={
        'locationId':{'S': 'a1'},
        'timestamp': {'N': str(time.time())
    },
    expected={
        'locationID': {'Exists': False}
    }
    #expected={
    #    'locationID': {'Exists': True, 'Value': {'N': '0'}}
    #}
)
```

Hope it helps!

Edit: [the question that helped me with the syntax enough to make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10338191/268939) and [code in the boto integration tests](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/tests/integration/dynamodb2/test_layer1.py#L270-L277)

Comment: I tried to use the code you provided but still has "TypeError: put_item() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expects'".  Without expected clause, it works (enters item and return true).

Comment: It should be "expected", not "expects" :)

Comment: sorry, I used the wrong error message. Even with `expected' I get the same error as following ... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: put_item() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expected'

Comment: @user2662898: And you're using dynamodb2? I run the same code and it's working for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the parameter `expected` of `put_item` is now [deprecated](https://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#boto.dynamodb2.layer1.DynamoDBConnection.put_item):

> Parameters:   expected (map)
>
> There is a newer parameter available. Use ConditionExpression instead.

Use `condition_expression` instead:

```py
connection.put_item(
    'table',
    item={
        'locationId': {'S': 'a1'}, 
        'timestamp': {'S': str(time.time())}
    },
    condition_expression='attribute_exists(locationId)'
)
```

It's also possible to chain expressions and to use named parameters, e.g:

```py
connection.put_item(
    'table',
    item={
        'locationId': {'S': 'a1'}, 
        'timestamp': {'S': str(time.time())}
    },
    condition_expression=(
        'attribute_exists(locationId) AND '
        'NOT attribute_type(locationId, :expected_type)'
    ),
    expression_attribute_values={
        ':expected_type': {'S': 'NULL'}  # String parameter of value 'NULL'
    }
)
```

[See *Performing Conditional Writes with Condition Expressions* for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html).