# DynamoDb stored object duplicates

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I wrote this function to see if an object has already been stored in dynamo.

```
def doesIDExist(key):
    print(key)
    info=key.split("/")
    #set properties
    try:
        id=info[1]+info[2]
        results = dynamoConn.query(swfTable,id)
        if results is not None:
            return True
    except:
        return False
    return False
```

I call a check before writing to any db:

```
 if(dynamoStorage.doesIDExist(theNewKey)==False):

      data= recursiveInnerFile(fPath,theNewKey)
      images = data[0]
      text = data[1]
      dynamoStorage.createSwfInDynamo(theNewKey,images,text)
```

and yet I still have duplicates showing up. What am I missing?

EDIT:

I'm not getting errors:
I am getting a table object and my function is returning True. But nothing is being added?

**Second Edit:
I solved this below.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid duplication the best way is to use "Conditional Put" so that if an item with the key already exists, the new item will not overwrite that existing item.

see the [doc](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb.html#boto.dynamodb.layer1.Layer1.put_item) for python

> Create a new item or replace an old item with a new item (including
>   all attributes). If an item already exists in the specified table with
>   the same primary key, the new item will completely replace the old
>   item. You can perform a conditional put by specifying an expected
>   rule.

[some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117561/boto-dynamodb2-conditional-put-item)

you just need need to pass the 'expected' as a dictionary to your put_item call.

```
expected={
    'yourHashKeyName': {'Exists': False}
}
```

The reason your code above doesn't work is dynamoConn.query will always return a TableGenerator object even when there is no item with that hash key.

The query function takes a [Count parameter](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb.html#boto.dynamodb.layer2.Layer2.query) which returns "a total number of items for the Query operation, even if the operation has no matching items for the assigned filter."

```
results = dynamoConn.query(swfTable,id, count = True)
```

and then check

```
results.count > 0
```

if that id already exists, results.count should be 1. otherwise it should be 0.

Another option is to use get_item API. your table doesn't have a range key and you can call get_item with the "id" as hashkey.

Comment: My concern is that the data is technically different ex different date and yet I want it to not overwrite based on the id. Can you explain the conditional put further? Will it work in circumstances based on ID only or does it need to be entirely the same? If a conditional put goes through and alters the file then I will lose the parts of my table that point to s3 files.

Comment: uniqueness is determined by ID only. none of the above solutions need your data as input.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I actually figured out what was wrong with my code. But this works as well.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this actually works in my case. I need to see if it exists so I can put other things. Ex if there is this created I will create other things in another table that are related. Does conditional put return a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The problem was that the object returned was not a table. I needed to get the table with .table and then get the count .item_count.

```
def doesIDExist(key):
    print(key)
    info=key.split("/")
    #set properties
    #try:
    id=info[1]+info[2]
    results = dynamoConn.query(swfTable,id).table.item_count
    print results
    if results > 0:
        return True
    #except:
    #    return False
    return False
```